# cpp:818: error: (-215:Assertion failed) buf.checkVector(1, CV_8U) > 0 in function 'imdecode_'

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use webcam to collect a photo and resizing it using cv2.resize(). But I am getting this error. I am using google colab. tensorflow==2.4.1 tensorflow-gpu==2.4.1 opencv-python matplotlib. cv2.resize suppose to take numpy array and dimension details as parameter. But everytime I am using it giving me this error. When I comment it out code works fine.

```
def take_photo(filename='photo.jpg', quality=0.8):
  js = Javascript('''
    async function takePhoto(quality) {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      const capture = document.createElement('button');
      capture.textContent = 'Capture';
      div.appendChild(capture);

      const video = document.createElement('video');
      video.style.display = 'block';
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});

      document.body.appendChild(div);
      div.appendChild(video);
      video.srcObject = stream;
      await video.play();

      // Resize the output to fit the video element.
      google.colab.output.setIframeHeight(document.documentElement.scrollHeight, true);

      // Wait for Capture to be clicked.
      await new Promise((resolve) => capture.onclick = resolve);

      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
      canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
      stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
      div.remove();
      return canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', quality);
    }
    ''')
  display(js)
 

 # get photo data
  data = eval_js('takePhoto({})'.format(quality))
  # get OpenCV format image
  img = js_to_image(data) 
  # grayscale img
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
  print(type(gray))
  #print(gray.shape)
  # get face bounding box coordinates using Haar Cascade
  faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray)
  # draw face bounding box on image
  for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
      img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
  # save image
  cv2.imwrite(filename, img)

  return filename
```

```
#@ js_to_data function

# function to convert the JavaScript object into an OpenCV image
def js_to_image(js_reply):
  """
  Params:
          js_reply: JavaScript object containing image from webcam
  Returns:
          img: OpenCV BGR image
  """
  
  # decode base64 image
  image_bytes = b64decode(js_reply.split(',')[1])
  # convert bytes to numpy array
  jpg_as_np = np.frombuffer(image_bytes, dtype=np.uint8)
  #Resize image
  jpg_as_np= cv2.resize(jpg_as_np,(250,250)) 
  jpg_as_np.shape
  # decode numpy array into OpenCV BGR image
  img = cv2.imdecode(jpg_as_np, flags=1) **#error here**
  

  return img

# function to convert OpenCV Rectangle bounding box image into base64 byte string to be overlayed on video stream
def bbox_to_bytes(bbox_array):
  """
  Params:
          bbox_array: Numpy array (pixels) containing rectangle to overlay on video stream.
  Returns:
        bytes: Base64 image byte string
  """
  # convert array into PIL image
  bbox_PIL = PIL.Image.fromarray(bbox_array, 'RGBA')
  iobuf = io.BytesIO()
  # format bbox into png for return
  bbox_PIL.save(iobuf, format='png')
  # format return string
  bbox_bytes = 'data:image/png;base64,{}'.format((str(b64encode(iobuf.getvalue()), 'utf-8')))

  return bbox_bytes
```

```
from numpy.lib import type_check

try:
  filename = take_photo()
  print(type(filename))
  print('Saved to {}'.format(filename))

 
Error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:818: error: (-215:Assertion failed) buf.checkVector(1, CV_8U) > 0 in function 'imdecode_'
```

Comment: img = cv2.imdecode(jpg_as_np, 1)  or img = cv2.imdecode(jpg_as_np, 0)

Comment: Still giving error.

Comment: There is something missing variable jpg_as_np.shape

Comment: img = cv2.imdecode(jpg_as_np, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCAL)

Comment: jpg_as_np.shape Output= (250, 250)

Comment: img = cv2.imdecode(jpg_as_np, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCAL) giving the error : module 'cv2' has no attribute 'IMREAD_GRAYSCAL'

Comment: It worked for me, If I used this jpg_original = base64.b64decode(string)
jpg_as_np = np.frombuffer(jpg_original, dtype=np.uint8)
img = cv2.imdecode(jpg_as_np, flags=1)

Comment: I can't understand. Is it because size mismatch? As I am resizing it to (250,250).

Comment: Put cv2.resiez after cv2.imdecode not before. Btw, I cannot got any further. That's all the troubleshooting I'm doing.

Comment: Using after it works fine. But still can not figure out why it doesn't work using before.